# Type of Project to be tested with Nunit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit, projects-and-solutions

I'm working on VS 2010 and myProject's type is a C# windows forms application.  When I add a new project to my solution and adding references for nunit and myProject I got the "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly" error. However if I don't use a separated project for my test classes, it works. Is it because myProject's type is not class library?

Note: I'm not testing GUI. Just some classes.

Comment: Pay attention to Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting.  The NUnit test runner must be compatible with your choice there.

Comment: Ideally, the code to be tested should be pulled out of the WinForms project and placed in a separate assembly.  That way, both the WinForms project and the test project can reference the code.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there way to accept a comment as a correct answer? I just changed platform target from x86 to Any CPU and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing that hinders you to add an NUnit reference to a WinForms application (after all, it is not different from a class lib from a pure technical standpoint).

The reason for the `BadImageFormatException` must come from a different source. In many cases it's a 32/64bit mismatch, or there might be some conflicting call conventions in place or sth. similar which goes in that direction. In any case, it has to be something compiler-related...

HTH - Thomas